# How to fix infinite bootloop problem in Sparkle V. Please help

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, boot, boot-loop, karbonn

I have a sparkle v which is unrooted and also I don't have any software like cwm.

My phone is stuck in an infinite bootloop. I tried removing the battery, going to recovery mode and factory resetting it and clearing cache.

I have marshmallow 6.0.1 in my phone before this problem.

None of those worked. Please help.

Comment: Did you tried to update OR tried to root OR tried to install custom recovery?

Comment: Yes, i tried if before when i am facing same problem. at that time i do boot my phone with STOCK ROM @RahulGopi

Comment: Did you tried to update stock ROM?

Comment: Yes! at that time it is working fine. and just two day before i am facing that same problem.

Comment: Did installation completed succesfully?

Comment: At that time it is fine but this time it will through error "E:/ Failed to Mount Cache (Invalid Argument)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57751/discussion-between-rahul-gopi-and-divyesh-gausvami).